# IIS Redirecting for different language versions

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have UrlRewrite 2.0 , IIS 7 - site with multiple languages - and need some redirection hopefully without having to define per language.

```
http://mycompany.com/
http://mycompany.com/de
http://mycompany.com/fr
http://mycompany.de
http://mycompany.fr
```

and for each of these cases i'd like to do a redirect like so

```
http://mycompany.com/widgetA --> http://mycompany.com/products/widgetA
http://mycompany.com/de/widgetA  --> http://mycompany.com/de/products/widgetA
http://mycompany.de/widgetA  --> http://mycompany.de/products/widgetA
```

Is this possible in a single rewrite rule?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> mycompany.(com|com/(de|fr)|de|fr)/.*